# Which episodes of Konjiki no Gash Bell are essential?

Tags: konjiki-no-gash-bell

The anime series of Konjiki no Gash Bell has 150 episodes. I watched up to episode 26. As far as I saw, in most of the episodes, the main plot does not advance. Watching all those 150 episodes will be very time-consuming if that's going to be the case for the rest of the series.

Please give me a list of the essential episodes so that I could skip over the non-essential ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://sjump-forum.livejournal.com/33717.html), there are 121 canon episodes.

> Filler episodes for Zatch Bell/Gash bell:
>
> - 31-35
> - 89-100
> - 139-150
>
> Once you reach the end of episode 138, read volume 22, chapter 212 to continue the story properly.
>
> 139-150 have parts in them that are canon, but they are not completely canon, they are mostly filler and the manga is better.